# Using update cursor in a while loop to perform analysis on individual polygons gets stuck on first row

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-2.7

I am working through an open courseware project from PSU found at https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/145

I am trying to use an update cursor in a  while loop to perform an analysis on individual polygons within a multipart feature. However, the output is for the first row ad infinitum.

Here is what i have so far:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/users/documents/arcgis/arcgis tutorials/psu tutorials/project3/policedata.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Declare variables for files and fields used in analysis

incidents = "c:/users/documents/arcgis/arcgis tutorials/psu tutorials/project3/policedata.gdb/GraffitiIncidents"
patrol_zones = "c:/users/documents/arcgis/arcgis tutorials/psu tutorials/project3/policedata.gdb/PatrolZones"
incidents_layer = "IncidentsLayer"
patrol_field = "NAME"

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(patrol_zones)
zone = cursor.next()

# Loop through each patrol zone

while zone:
    try:
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(incidents,"IncidentsLayer" )
        zone_name = zone.getValue(patrol_field)
        print zone_name

        sql = patrol_field + " = " + "'" + zone_name + "'"

    # Make a feature layer for each zone
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(patrol_zones, "CurrentZone", sql)


    # Make selection
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(incidents_layer, "CONTAINED_BY", "CurrentZone")
        num_incidents = arcpy.GetCount_management(incidents_layer)


        print "Graffitti incidents = " + str(num_incidents)
##        arcpy.Delete_management("CurrentZone")
##        zone
    except:
        print "Could not perform analysis."


del cursor
```

What in my code is causing the script to produce results only for the first row?

Comment: Don't do `while zone:`, do `for zone in iter(cursor.next, None):`. Missing the `.next()` call or not reaching it in a certain `if` condition is a common pitfall with old-style arcpy cursors. Better yet, use [`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000).

Comment: @JasonScheirer Thanks, your edit worked. I have not had exposure to the iter() function before. If you move your comment to an answer I will accept it so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are missing another

```
zone = cursor.next()
```

within the While loop

You need to increment the cursor to the next feature after you're done with it or the loop starts over on the same feature.

```
incidents = r"c:\users\documents\arcgis\arcgis tutorials\psu tutorials\project3\policedata.gdb\GraffitiIncidents"
patrol_zones = r"c:\users\documents\arcgis\arcgis tutorials\psu tutorials\project3\policedata.gdb\PatrolZones"
incidents_layer = "IncidentsLayer"
patrol_field = "NAME"

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(patrol_zones)
zone = cursor.next()

# Loop through each patrol zone

while zone:
    try:
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(incidents,"IncidentsLayer" )
        zone_name = zone.getValue(patrol_field)
        print zone_name

        sql = patrol_field + " = " + "'" + zone_name + "'"

        # Make a feature layer for each zone
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(patrol_zones, "CurrentZone", sql)

        # Make selection
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(incidents_layer, "CONTAINED_BY", "CurrentZone")
        num_incidents = arcpy.GetCount_management(incidents_layer)

        print "Graffitti incidents = " + str(num_incidents)
    except:
        print "Could not perform analysis."

    zone = cursor.next()

del cursor
```

An alternative to having to add a `.next()` call (and avoid the potential for misplacing it) is to use the `iter` builtin function:

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(patrol_zones)
for zone in iter(cursor.next, None):
    # (Code)
```

Comment: Added cursor.next() to end of loop and now the result hangs on the second entry.

Comment: @Jyler did you put it in the right place?

Comment: @JasonScheirer No, actually I had it dedented from the while: loop. It works, now, thank you.